# Search in the middle of a string

Tags: dom, vbscript

I have a small panel in a webpage which displays some summary information. I used VBScript DOM to retrieve the summary information. The string looks very crude like this. There would be one line in between and sometimes it could be 2 or 3 lines between the strings.

```
Info

Total : 20

Priority


Pri1: 20

Pri2: 0



Other:0

State

Open: 20
```

1. I want to check what is the value displayed beside Total in the above string?
2. I retrieved the above string using `Node.innerText`. The Node has lots of children Div tags and each div tag holds one string. So when I said `Node.innerText`, it retrieved everything as a big string like above. Is there a way to search for a particular string and retrieve only that?

Comment: show us piece of html to understand more about the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex to extract the value after the word "Total". Will it always be an integer?

```
' Get the string...
s = Node.innerText

With New RegExp
    .Pattern = "Total : (\d+)"
    Set m = .Execute(s)
End With

If m.Count > 0 Then MsgBox m(0).SubMatches(0)    ' ==> 20
```